# Laravel how to disable/remove route cache

Tags: laravel-5

I am busy with a Laravel upgrade 5.4 to 5.8 and getting error Unable to prepare route xxx for serialization. Use s Closure.

I have a lot of Closures in my `web.php` and not planning to refactor it.

Is it possible and how tot remove/disable route caching?

Error:

```
   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [login] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at C:\App\lv-5-8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for seriali
zation. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919|
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921|

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      C:\App\lv-5-8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.
php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      C:\App\lv-5-8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:32

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my `composer.json` there was `php artisan optimize` that was deprecated in Laravel 5.6.
So i removed this and it works.

Answer (score 3):

A basic `php artisan route:clear`
But if you upgrade to new version. You can remove about the cache folder in `bootstrap/cache` for anything.
Then run some command line below

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan key:generate`

`composer dump-autoload`

Good luck!

Comment: @Bas Please post all your errors on communicate. We have many hero can to help solve that.

Answer (score 1):

you're caching configs & routes.
as I used to do, by running a multiple commands

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize
```

this way every time I made a change in `routes/web.php` or `config/app.php` I would've to run above commands to apply changes then cache them again and again, which is annoying.

So I fixed it by doing so:

```
@REM php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
@REM php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
@REM php artisan optimize
```

Now every change I made in config and routes works instantly without resetting cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php artisan route:clear` command to clear route cache :)

The help doc from route:clear command

```
Description:
  Remove the route cache file

Usage:
  route:clear

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

Comment: Normally the route cache file is at bootstrap/cache/routes.php. You can try delete it and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Still getting the error LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [xxx/xxx] for serialization. Uses Closur
e.

Comment: Does this error shows up when you run route:cache? or route:clear?. I asked this because route:cache won't allow caching if the route file has at least one route's method as a closure.

Comment: php artisan route:cache

Comment: I see, the only way it would work is if you refactor all closure in web.php into its own controller class. Then route:cache command should no longer shows an error. You should be able to try this by commenting out the closure routes, then run route:cache.

Comment: i don't like this solution to remove all my closures into the controllers, i have a lot... Isn't there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Open a config file in the app/config depending on Laravel version

Example:

app/config/view.php file then set 'cache' => false